# Необходимо написать функцию на Python, просматривающую содержание словаря и возвращающую ключи тех элементов, которые являются массивами Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, словари

Вернее, что-то уже написано:

```
def smth(t, **kwargs):
for i in enumerate(kwargs):
    if type(kwargs.get(i[1]))=="<class 'numpy.ndarray'>": print(i[1])
```

просто не работает нормально: при вводе

```
smth('Name', time=0, x=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]), y=34, z=np.array([34, 57, 81]))
```

не выдает ровным счетом ничего. А сравниваю я именно с такой строкой, поскольку функция

```
def smth(t, **kwargs):
for i in enumerate(kwargs):
    print(type(kwargs.get(i[1])))
```

на тех же входных данных выдает:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Было бы здорово, если подскажете решение проблемы

Comment: if isinstance (variable, np.ndarray) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы проверит тип надо писать так

```
if type(kwargs.get(i[1])) == np.ndarray:
```

`enumerate` можно убрать

```
def smth(t, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs:
        if type(kwargs[key] )==np.ndarray:
            print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась заменой строчки

```
if type(kwargs.get(i[1]))=="<class 'numpy.ndarray'>": print(i[1])
```

на

```
if str(type(kwargs.get(i[1])))=="<class 'numpy.ndarray'>": print(i[1])
```

т. е. добавилась функция str()